# Path of particle under gravity

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

If a particle is subjected to gravity then
        $$\frac{∂^2 u}{∂\theta^2} +u = \frac{GM}{h^2} $$
where 
       $$ u = \frac{1}{r}$$
and
        $$h = r^2\dot{\theta}.$$
If you solve this you get 
        $$u = A\sin\theta+B\cos\theta + \frac{GM}{h^2}.$$
But the general solution for this is just in terms of $\cos\theta$ because then you have the eqn for a conic. So why is $A = 0$?

Comment: I believe the convention is to chose the direction of the line of apses for the orbit to be aligned with  $ \ \theta = 0 \ $ , so as to eliminate the sine term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also write the general solution to this differential equation (under a fixed set of polar coordinates) as 
$$u = C_1 \cos(\theta+C_2) + \frac{GM}{h^2}$$
by defining $C_1=\sqrt{A^2+B^2}$ and $C_2=\tan^{-1}\left(\dfrac{A}B\right)$.

However, by redefining $\theta=0$ appropriately, we can have the same solution with $C_2=0$, leaving us with only a cosine term.