# Calculus involving a Physics problem

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

This is the equation that occurs in a particular problem in physics. If earth falls into the sun if it stopped orbiting suddenly.

$\mathrm{d}r = \frac{GM}{2r^2} \mathrm{dt}^2$[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jjScL.jpg)

This is my attempted solution. Is it correct? Also can someone explain how on one side we have only one integral and on the other side we have two? If we integrate one side of the equation, surely we must also integrate the other side as well. No? So how come we integrate one side once and the other side twice.

$\int_{0}^{R}\frac{2r^2}{GM}\mathrm{d}r=\int_{0}^{T}\int\mathrm{d}t^2$

This becomes $\frac{T^2}{2}=\frac{2R^3}{3GM}$

Comment: That equation doesn’t make sense to me.

Comment: Does this come from $${d^2r\over dt^2}={GM\over2r^2}$$ If so, then solving it is not as simple as integrating twice, because you're given the second derivative as a function of $r$, not $t$.

Comment: The question looks a little bit like this one: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/423098/path-of-particle-under-gravity

Comment: This equation is derived if the earth suddenly stopped orbiting and fell into the sun. But that is not the question. The question is that if we have an equation like the one above, is the solution correct?

Comment: It is impossible to say if the equation is correct or not because you haven't told us what the variables represent!  In particular, what is "dt"?  It looks like a differential but it can't be because you don't have a corresponding differential, squared, on the other side of the equation.

Comment: The question isn't whether the solution is correct, the question is what is the equation supposed to be, since, as we've been trying to tell you, the equation as you have written it makes no sense. You have what looks like a 1st derivative on the left, and what looks like a 2nd derivative on the right. Please, please, please check your source to see whether what you've written as an equation is really what you want (and if it is, what does it actually mean?).

Comment: An answer was posted two days ago, Adeel. What do you think of it? If it answers your question, I'd encourage you to "accept" it by clicking in the check mark next to it. If it doesn't answer your question, I'd encourage you to comment on it to indicate what more you need to see.

Comment: Ok I have added an image that represents my full solution. Please see that!

Comment: I have found the solution on the internet based on calculus. https://www.physlink.com/Education/AskExperts/ae226.cfm

Answer (score 1):

You've misunderstood how to set up second-order differential equations.

A body that falls vertically has $\frac{d^2r}{dt^2}=-\frac{GM}{r^2}$. This has a number of implications you were considering that I review in the paragraph below, but it is this equation alone that we use to solve for $r$ as a function of $t$, e.g. as in [@GerryMyerson's link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/423098/path-of-particle-under-gravity).

Over short enough falls with initially zero speed for $r$ to change little (this is the simplest case to analyze), the acceleration is approximately constant, so $r\approx r_0-\frac{GM}{2r_0^2}t^2$, where $r_0$ is the $t=0$ value of $r$. On the other hand, at small times $dt$ we have$$r\approx r_0+\underbrace{\dot{r}_0}_0dt+\tfrac12\ddot{r}_0dt^2=r-\tfrac{GM}{2r_0^2}dt^2,$$i.e. the change in $r$ is $-\tfrac{GM}{2r_0^2}dt^2$. However, at a later time when $r$ has reduced, $\dot{r}$ has become negative and the elapsed time is no longer negligible, the result is rather different.

Comment: See image added!

Comment: @AdeelMalik The correct method is in Sec. 1.1 [here](http://astro.physics.uiowa.edu/~srs/2961_12/Lec09_notes.pdf).

Comment: This uses elliptical equations and then assumes the eccentricity is a very large number. It's not essentially a calculus based problem. Actually I have found it here... It does use integral calculus... https://www.physlink.com/Education/AskExperts/ae226.cfm

Comment: @AdeelMalik A very large number? For closed orbits, $e<1$. We need calculus to prove the orbit is a closed section.